# alpha vantage does not show same day prices

Tags: api, stock, alpha-vantage

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=TFC&apikey=
```

the above alpha vantage Api request does not show todays price for any symbol(note Api key was omitted).

Answer (score 2):

Your request for "TIME_SERIES_DAILY" shows historical prices.  The Alpha Vantage API doesn't show real-time intraday prices.  As they hint at in their documentation where they refer you to another provider:

"If you are interested in realtime intraday data for US stocks and ETFs, we have partnered with Polygon.io, a leading provider of realtime market data that counts Google and Robinhood as its customers."

https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#intraday

Comment: we use alpha so we can get free real time data and polygon from my experience is no better, I think the best thing to do is to use alpaca its free.